# Displaying custom module content in a popup from other page

Tags: 7

I have a custom module which displays listings and info about realties. How can I display realty's images in a popup from other page? 
In example I have info about realty on realty/566 and it's images can be viewed realtyimages/566

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module.
It will display it in the same window but look like a pop-up in page, like in Facebook.